# Cannot create Header based external HTTPS LBS routing rules on existing Kubernetes service in Google Cloud

Tags: gcloud, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service, google-cloud-http-load-balancer

I'm trying to change an existing external HTTPS LBS configuration to apply advanced custom-header based routing rules on GCloud, but get the following error when updating the url-map

**HTTPError 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.defaultService': ... Advanced routing rules are not supported for scheme EXTERNAL**

The current setup is a Kubernetes workload (deployment) exposed as a service and has path-based ingress rules. FYI- Path-based LBS works.

*Sample url-map*

```
kind: compute#urlMap
name: k8s-um-development-lbs-test
defaultService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/beans-cloud/global/backendServices/backend-1
hostRules:
- hosts:
  - '*'
  pathMatcher: user-agent-matcher
pathMatchers:
- name: user-agent-matcher
  routeRules:
    - matchRules:
        - prefixMatch: /
          headerMatches:
            - headerName: User-Agent
              regexMatch: "*Pattern-1*"
      priority: 0
      service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/beans-cloud/global/backendServices/backend-1
    - matchRules:
        - prefixMatch: /
          headerMatches:
            - headerName: User-Agent
              regexMatch: "*Pattern-2*"
      priority: 1
      service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/beans-cloud/global/backendServices/backend-2
  defaultService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/beans-cloud/global/backendServices/backend-1
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/beans-cloud/global/urlMaps/k8s-um-development-lbs-test
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to confirm that is only possible to use it with [HTTP(s) Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-traffic-management), So, if you wanted to rewrite or modify the URL, please review how to [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-url-rewrite).

Just to have more references, [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/setting-up-traffic-management#url_map_yaml_examples) is another reference, but please consider that this is only for Internal Load Balancer (Also HTTP(s)).

And as a last thing, I add information about that currently is not possible to custom the headers for external HTTP(s) Load Balancers, please put a comment [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/165109880), in order to be informed about any update about it.

Regards and Happy New Year.